# New employer not giving me onboarding information

Tags: communication

I am supposed to start working in a trustworthy company in a company next Monday. The company has two offices I have to work in. I signed the contract three months ago. I heard from the boss via email three and four weeks ago about my ID and registration card for the building, but this week they didn't send me anything about which building I'm supposed to start in, or whether they work from home, etc.

Someone has to tell me where I will start and what my first task is etc, but I still haven't heard anything. Today is Wednesday, and this week I need to know these things, since I start working on Monday.

I'm a bit concerned as to why they haven't written to me with details about my first day of work yet. I still have tomorrow and Friday. I want to write to ask about these things, but at the same time I feel like maybe I should let them contact me about it. Should I contact them or should I wait until Friday? (I hope they haven't backed off and changed their mind about my employment.)

Comment: Pick up your phone and call either your hiring manager or your recruiter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: If you have a signed contract, they probably just can't "change their mind" like that...

Comment: Is there a more descriptive title that can be applied to this question?

Comment: Do not wait until the last minute. If you want to appear competent as an employee, you have to show that you're willing to make phone calls when you need to make them. If you don't do this, nothing will be ready when you get there as it may take a couple of days to prepare your office, your computer, etc. If I were you, I would send an email and then immediately make a phone call within 10 minutes of that email. In the email, send it to both HR and to your new manager.

Answer (score 13):

1. Find phone number of the most HR-like contact you have at your new employer.
   1a. If you don't have a number, use the main number listed on their website.
2. Phone said number.
3. Explain that you're starting on Monday but haven't heard any details.
4. Respond appropriately to any questions you're asked.

Most likely, you've either slipped through a crack somewhere or they've sent a ton of details to an e-mail address with one character different from yours and are wondering why you haven't responded.

(And if in the worst case scenario they have changed their mind, you get two days extra to start job hunting again. Better to know now than 5 PM on Friday)

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the already good answers provided, I would like to cover the scenario where you don't manage to get ANY answer before Monday. It seems obvious but in that case, certainly don't stay at home waiting for an answer, choose one of both offices, and go there. 4 possibilities here:

- You're in the right office. Nice!
- You're in the wrong office. Too bad. They will quickly figure that out and you'll need to go to the other office, but at least you were there on time, you can't be blamed for their failed communication on this.
- You were not actually supposed to go in any office physically because everybody is working from home. I think this would have been mentioned in the previous communication when talking about access badge (useless if you're not on-site), but you never know... If this happens try to get a hold on your manager and ask for the next steps. Maybe for example you can already pick-up some laptop or any work material.
- They changed their mind and ghosted you big time. This is probably the least possible outcome, especially if you have a signed contract. If that's the case though, you can't change that, but you may have dodged a bullet as working for a company treating future employees like that may not be enjoyable anyway.

Comment: Well formulated addition to phillips answer, especially the last of the 4 possibilites..

Answer (score 3):

Don't drown in a glass of water. Send them an e-mail or pick up the phone and call them.

Spending 5 minutes now to answer that question will save them and you much more time on Monday, should you show up at the wrong reception.

Simply ask where and when are you supposed to show up on Monday, office A or office B?

HR are usually always very busy and it can happen that they overlooked sending that mail to you.